# Append line of text to Azure Block Blob from Android

Tags: android, azure-blob-storage

I want to append a line of text to an existing Azure cloud block blob from an Android device.

In VB.Net I would AcquireLease, getBlockBlobReference, DownloadToFile, add the line on the local files system, UploadToFile, ReleaseLease . Simple and secure, if a bit long-winded.

In Android, it looks a little more tricky. At the moment, my best solution is this:

```
                CloudBlockBlob blob1=container.getBlockBlobReference(chosenOne+".txt"); 

                String proposedLeaseId1 = UUID.randomUUID().toString(); 
                OperationContext operationContext1 = new OperationContext();
                blob1.acquireLease(15, proposedLeaseId1, null /*access condition*/,null/* BlobRequestOptions */, operationContext1);

                AccessCondition condition = new AccessCondition();
                condition.setLeaseID(proposedLeaseId1);

                BlobInputStream blobIn = blob1.openInputStream();

                blob1.downloadAttributes();
                long blobLengthToUse = blob1.getProperties().getLength();

                byte[] result = new byte[(int) blobLengthToUse];
                blob1.downloadToByteArray(result,0);

                blobIn.close();

                CloudBlockBlob blob1 = container.getBlockBlobReference(chosenOne+".txt");   

                String proposedLeaseId1 = UUID.randomUUID().toString(); 
                OperationContext operationContext1 = new OperationContext();
                blob1.acquireLease(15, proposedLeaseId1, null /*access condition*/,null/* BlobRequestOptions */, operationContext1);


                AccessCondition condition = new AccessCondition();
                condition.setLeaseID(proposedLeaseId1);

                BlobInputStream blobIn = blob1.openInputStream();

                blob1.downloadAttributes();
                long blobLengthToUse = blob1.getProperties().getLength();
                byte[] result = new byte[(int) blobLengthToUse];
                blob1.downloadToByteArray(result,0);

                blobIn.close();

                blob1.deleteIfExists(DeleteSnapshotsOption.NONE,condition, null, operationContext1);

                BlobOutputStream blobOut = blob1.openOutputStream(); 

                //this is a byte by byte write ...
                //which is fine ... but no use if you want to replace ...
                /*int next = blobIn.read();
                while (next != -1) {
                      blobOut.write(next);
                      next = blobIn.read();
                }*/

                blobOut.write(result);

                String strTemp="This is just a test string";

                blobOut.write(strTemp.getBytes());

                blobOut.close();
```

Apart from being extremely long-winded, I am concerned that as soon as I delete the blob, the lease will go and that I may hit integrity issues. I would appreciate any help in making this code simpler and more secure. I know that Microsoft are planning to introduce append blobs in 3Q 2015, but I want to implement this now.

Comment: I might be missing something, but have you taken a look at the uploadFromFile and downloadToFile methods on CloudBlockBlob? It seems like with these you could do something very similar to what you described doing in VB.Net.

Comment: Thanks, Emily. I will check that out when I return from holiday next week. Most likely, it is ME who is missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call PutBlock to upload the appended content (the maximum size of each block is 4MB, so please split the appended content into blocks if required), and then call PutBlockList on this blob by passing in the previously committed blocks plus and newly appended blocks.